# Issue in af:showDetailItem under panelAccordion component not getting the label after migrating source code from 12.2.1.3 to 12.2.1.4 J developer

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf

### Problem Description

Our code is running in 12.2.1.3.0 Jdeveloper and now deployed upgraded version on the 12.2.1.4.0 weblogic server
due to this we faced issue in af:showDetailItem under panelAccordion component not getting the label on UI before the upgrade it's working fine.
below is the piece of code which is working in our older weblogic version 12.2.1.3.0 and not working in upgraded version on the 12.2.1.4.0 weblogic server -

Source Code-

```
<af:panelAccordion id="pa1" discloseMany="false" discloseNone="true"
                           styleClass="#{(pageFlowScope.recordView == pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.selectAllView or pageFlowScope.recordView == pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.selectView or pageFlowScope.recordView == pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.selectFullView) ? 'Accordion' : ''}"
                           partialTriggers="b1 b2 b3">
<af:iterator value="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.caseAlt == 1 ? bindings.CategoryVO1.collectionModel : bindings.CategoryVO2.collectionModel}"
                       var="cat" id="it1" rows="-1" binding="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.categoryIterator}">
<af:showDetailItem text="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.truncatedCategory} (#{cat.DocumentCount})" id="sd1"
                               disclosureListener="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.changeCategory}"
                               visible="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.categoryVisible}" rendered="true"
                               disclosed="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.categoryDisclosed}"                    disclosedTransient="true"
                               flex="1"
                               styleClass='#{cat.IsRecordAdded == 1 ? "HighlightedRecordCategory" : "RegularRecordCategory"}'
                               binding="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.categoryTab}"
                               shortDesc="#{pageFlowScope.ThumbnailMB.category}">
```

so, here above `showDetailItem` text is not displaying , and even hard coded text is not displaying.

Wanted to know why labels are missing in J developer 12.2.1.4 version same code is working fine in J developer 12.2.1.3?

Comment: Have you checked the resulting web page using dev tools of your browser? 

Check if the text is part of the page but not visible due to some CSS. As a test you can remove the styleClass property from the showDetailItem.